# Text in grid overlapping

Tags: html, css

2nd day working on my site. So far it's looking all right, but when I change the size of the site (via mouse scroll), text paragraphs in different items are overlapping each other. It doesn't look nice, what to do? 
Also, did I made the right thing to put three first paragraphs as one grid, two latter as second grid? I wanted the fourth paragraph to be on the width of the first two columns. Is there an easier way to clean up the code?

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    text-align: right;
    color: #dfbf9f;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: #999999;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

        li a:hover {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
        }

        li a:visited {
            background-color: #d9d9d9 !important;
        }

.welcome {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01aef0 45%, #0090d7 100%);
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

#lorem {
    color: #80dfff !important;
    -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-before: -15px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 10px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-weight:300;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.description {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #808080;
}

#title {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.ostatnie {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }


footer {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-spacing: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

ol {
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramaraja" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
 
 <div class="welcome">
  <header>
            <h1><em>welcome</em></h1>
   <h2 id="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>
        </header>
    </div>


<div class="grid">
 <div id="t1">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Who Are We?</em></h2>
  <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 
 <div id="t2">
 <h2 id="title"><em>What We Do?</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 
 <div id="t3">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Latest Projects</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ostatnie">
 <div id="t4">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="t5">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typeset</p>
 </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <ol>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about us</li>
        <li>services</li>
        <li>solutions</li>
        <li>support</li>
        <li>partners</li>
        <li>contact</li>
    </ol>
</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Stupid question, but why are you emphasizing everything?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, why do I put every description in class=description? I am very new to coding, so I am not entirely sure if this is necessary or not.

Comment: No, I meant you put so many things in <em>..</em> tags.

Comment: It's for the style, I guess I could do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you would want to remove these 2 lines from your css code `.grid` to get your desired result.

```
height: 300px;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Your new css should be something like this

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked! Also, can I group all 5 paragraphs in one grid and still have the same effect?